# Read files in Xposed module

Tags: android, file, xposed

I am trying to read a file in an xposed module. The file resides in `/data/data/<my package name>/files/`

I tried this -

```
File conf = new File(Environment.getDataDir()+"/data/<my package name>/files/filename");

BaseService baseService = SELinuxHelper.getAppDataFileService();

InputStream inputStream = baseService.getFileInputStream(conf.getName());
```

And then using the `inputStream` to read the file. However it's giving me `Permission denied` error.

So, how can I access my files in xposed class.

Answer (score 1):

In `InputStream inputStream = baseService.getFileInputStream(conf.getName());` you are passing name of the file as the parameter to the `BaseService.getFileInputStream(String)` whereas you are supposed to pass absolute path of the file, according to XposedBridge API[0].

[0]http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/services/BaseService.html#getFileInputStream(java.lang.String)